# How to change the Dashboard Preferences to "As Overlay" in applescript

Tags: applescript

I'm making an applescript which automates adding dashboard widgets to the desktop. To do this I need to set the Dashboard settings to "As Overlay" instead of "As Space" or "Off". This is in System Preferences > Mission Control. Also, how do I do stop the script until the return/enter key is pressed? This is what I have to far (without changing settings or the enter key):

`set icon to (path to me as string) & "Contents:Resources:icon.icns"
on delay duration
    set endTime to (current date) + duration
    repeat while (current date) is less than endTime
        tell AppleScript to delay duration
    end repeat
end delay
delay 2
do shell script "defaults write com.apple.dashboard devmode YES"
delay 2
do shell script "killall Dock"
delay 3
display dialog "Click and hold to select a widget" with title "DeskWidget" buttons {"Cancel", "Choose a Widget"} default button 2 with icon file icon
delay 2
tell application "System Events"
    key code 111
end tell`

the return/enter key would be here, but instead I just have `delay 2`

`tell application "System Events"
    key code 111
end tell
delay 3
do shell script "killall Dock"`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the Dashboard settings to "**As Overlay**" (tested on **El Capitan**), use this :

```
do shell script "defaults write com.apple.dashboard 'dashboard-enabled-state' -int 3 && defaults write com.apple.dashboard 'enabled-state' -int 2 && sleep 2 && killall Dock"
```

---

To get the pressed keys: it's not possible with AppleScript, this should be possible in a Cocoa-Applet (`AppleScriptObjC` code)

Comment: Thats ok, the enter/return thing wasn't that necessary anyway. Thanks